What is כתיבת מלאכים, what is it for, and where does it derive from?
I have seen various writings called כתיבת מלאכים. In one case, I saw symbols in the end of Sefer Raziel haMalach written in a distinct script. In another case, a while back, I was in a shtieble and someone had some papers sticking out of his sidur written in such a script. The writing was referenced by haRav Mutzafi that the piyut האדרת והאמונה was in כתיבת מלאכים in ספר הריקמה.
I tried looking into the meaning of the term כתיבת מלאכים and could not find any sources online explaining what the script actually is, where it came from, what it means, and if it was for or by malachim - why was it found in human documents?
Could anyone help answer these questions?

There are numerous seforim discussing this from the Rishonim but the earliest sources I have seen are attributed to Daniel the Prophet. There is a tradition  about this within the Temani community and have been books in print from manuscripts over the last several years. There is a distinct script for each of the Angels together with their specific seal.
